# C : Unable to represent negative values with signed int

Tags: c, integer, hex, signed, twos-complement

I have to write a code for my university project that reads through a binary file and prints out integer values. This is just a small snippet of what I wrote:

```
signed int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            print("Value of n=%d", ch);
    }
```

However, I can't get it to print out negative values. What I mean is, if the value if 33, 33 is printed, otherwise if the value is -33, 223 is given out.I'm still a beginner and sorry for the bad code. I tried reading the values as hex and then printing out, but that doesn't work. Reading the file with %d also doesn't work. I can get the values correct by converting the number to binary, checking the sign bit, and then doing a 2's complement but I have to return the value properly at a later stage without any operation, so it's not a feasible solution. To sum up, I want to read a negative value, store it, and print it without any other operation. If someone knows what I'm doing wrong, please help! And sorry again if this a beginner question.

Comment: You are first reading a character with `fgetc` discarding its result and then attempting to read a number with `fscanf`. I doubt this is what you really want to do.

Comment: You also specified a maximum field width of 0, which is not allowed.

Comment: You say the file is binary, but `fscanf` reads a text-formatted number. What exactly does your data look like?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the quick reply. I don't know how that slipped my mind, Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @interjay I tried reading using %04x but that doesn't work too. I'll edit the code though. The file is a JVM file. The hex dump looks something like this: 3102AFF. As binary: 00000011000100000010101011111111. I hope that makes it clear!

Comment: Then it's a binary file. `fscanf` is used for text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I can't get it to print out negative values.

```
signed int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        print("Value of n=%d", ch); 
}
```

`fgetc(fp)` returns a value in the `unsigned char` range or `EOF`.
All non-`EOF` values would necessarily never be negative<sup>1</sup>.

> ... the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` ...  C17dr § 7.21.7.1 2

---

If OP wants to read, say 32 bits of binary data, and interpret that as an integer:

```
int32_t i;
while (fread(&i, sizeof i, 1, fp) > 0) {
  printf("%ld\n", (long) i);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Pedantic exception. When `char` size same as `int`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It works all right, only that I changed the int32_t to int8_t and everything falls into place. Thanks!